# Are the dark toolbars also coming to gtk2 applications?

Tags: themes, gtk

The gtk3 theme in Oneiric has seen some improvements: dark toolbars and those awesome scrollbars I just discovered (when not using the overlay scrollbars). Are these improvements also coming to the gtk2 theme so we have consistency between gtk2 and gtk3 applications?

[image: gtk3]
[image: gtk2]

Comment: Care to illustrate your question with some pictures?

Comment: I like the dark toolbars but I hadn't noticed that they are only in gtk3 apps. Good question then!

Comment: yes, you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already have that in Natty. It is unlikely that it will be an official 'backport' since that's not Ubuntu's way.

- All credits go to James Schriver/`Dashua` from launchpad.
- Only for Natty.
- From [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/add-ubuntu-one-style-dark-toolbars-to-all-apps-in-ubuntu/):

**Global dark toolbars**

Put together by Dashua, [the following Natty-only PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dashua/+archive/ppa) contains a modified version of the Ubuntu light themes that applies this ‘dark toolbar’ style to all of your installed GTK+ applications.

As this ‘style’ is very much in-progress it doesn’t work correctly with all applications. Bear this in mind before installing, and make a back-up of the original Ambiance theme in case you wish to revert.

Also provided via Dashua’s PPA is a patched version of `Nautilus-Elementary`.

**Getting the changes**

You can upgrade your version of Ambiance and Nautilus with these unsupported changes by adding `ppa:dashua/ppa` to your software sources (see the `Technical details about this PPA` on [how to add a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dashua/+archive/ppa/+index#)).

Once added, run the `Update Manager` to apply the relevant updates. Select `Ambiance` in the `Appearance Properties` window for the theme to take effect. You may need to log out and back in in-order for changes to Nautilus to appear.

Also note that this version of Ambiance has `Faenza` set as the default icon set. If you don’t wish to use the Faenza icon pack you can change. Click the `customize` button in `Appearance Preferences`, go to the `icon` tab and choose an icon set of your choosing. The default `Ubuntu icon set` is `Ubuntu Mono Dark`.

And it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: A backport to natty is indeed unlikely but Natty isn't that much of a problem (all applications have bright toolbars). The problem are gtk2 applications in Oneiric (there are still many) and the resulting inconsistency.

Comment: You are not asking this for Oneiric since that is alpha and questions are closed since Oneiric is buggy and still being worked on so every question might have a different correct answer ;) For For Natty this works ;-)

Comment: I didn't know Oneiric questions are closed. I probably should have asked the developers on Launchpad. Didn't come to my mind, though.

Comment: Try this PPA on Oneiric with Natty as distribution. Good chance it will work.